# lvcreate reports disk full, vgdisplay says space still exists

Tags: xen, lvm

I'm attempting to create some new lvm partitions for a Xen VM. The drives are already set up - running `sudo vgdisplay` give me the following:

```
 --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               n3850a-vg0
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  15
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               219.02 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              56068
  Alloc PE / Size       13020 / 50.86 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       43048 / 168.16 GiB
  VG UUID               kctW6H-n49O-35Dd-8wCt-qc3k-l8p3-iwqqPo
```

and `sudo pvdisplay`:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               n3850a-vg0
  PV Size               82.50 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              21120
  Free PE               8100
  Allocated PE          13020
  PV UUID               ofPxFv-4qx4-KOBL-VaEa-C19z-dGgO-Unqyur

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               n3850a-vg0
  PV Size               136.52 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              34948
  Free PE               34948
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               nP2rog-Sgee-mBFN-2fhG-wt9w-7cdi-QriTpo
```

However, if I try to run, for example `sudo lvcreate n3850a-vg0 -L 16M -n testpart`, I get:

```
  /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_n3850a_12308_1737345472: write error failed: No space left on device
  Volume group "n3850a-vg0" metadata archive failed.
```

I didn't set up the initial system (the person who did isn't available). I've dialed back my initial requests to 16M for  debugging, and even that doesn't work. Additionally, attempting to boot any of the other VMs fails with the same error.
`df -i` reports inode use to be ~1%, so that's not the issue (like some other askers).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The error message doesn't say anything about you lacking space in the volume group. It says you don't have any space left in `/etc`!

Comment: Wow, duh. xen-create-image originally gave me error 1280, so I just assumed it was a problem with the logical group. Cleaned up some old files, and back in business! Thanks!